# IE8 not working with apache basic auth

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, apache2

Basically what happens is when I go to the site ie8 pops up the prompt for logging in, I provide credentials and hit "ok".  The popup comes up again, I repeat, same result. I've repeated up to 10 times and still ie never logs me in, if I hit cancel I get logged in (after several attempts)

This works fine on firefox and chrome.  Any thoughts about why this would be happening in IE?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what may be the problem but I'd suggest to debug the HTTP traffic using Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Please show the .htaccess file in question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it out, the apache Directory Index value was not set, so Firefox et, al didn't have a problem but IE would see no file specified (just a folder) and somehow things were breaking down between the server and browser. When the value was set, the issue resolved itself.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to peek the traffic and make sure that IE decided to use basic auth.  Perhaps Apache is responding that it accepts more than basic, and IE is using a different authentication (which fails).